# GPS Specific questions for Service application

Tags: basic4android

I am working on a simple application that I need to be run as a service and report gps position every 3 minutes. I already have a working example based on the tutorial, but still have the followin doubts.

1. The starting of the service   `GPS1.Start(5*60*1000, 0)`
   Says first parameter is time lapse, and 2nd parameter is distance difference, How is determined, based on prior position ?
2. If I want to do what I stated before and I am scheduling / starting service every 3 minutes, this means I will need to ask a `GPS1.Start(0,0)` to get latest fix? what would be the gain to use the parameters?
3. I trying in a NexusOne and the Time object comes with local time, I have to do this to make it UTC but this is a tweak to the code. Is this a standard or could It change based on Phone model ? `hora=DateTime.Date(Location1.Time + 6*DateTime.TicksPerHour)`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in a single fix each time then you should pass 0, 0. These values affect the frequency of subsequent events.

You can find the time zone with the code posted here: [GetTimeZone](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/11666-how-calculate-get-gmt.html#post65152)

Comment: following up with  your comment I tested my service all day today moving, now is more consistent with reports and no unnecesary ones, will change to (0,0) and will let you know

Comment: I forgot to ask, is there a way to get a less accurate fix, like network data, for other purposes that need less accuracy ?

Comment: Yes, with ABWifi library: [link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/additional-libraries-official-updates/8613-wifi-library.html)